# how to get only min_price value records in mongodb using query

Tags: spring, mongodb

This is json data

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58107ee67a6e3f0504a2a14c"), 
    "_class" : "com.careheors.services.model.main.TangoRewards", 
    "brands" : [
        {
            "description" : "Tango Card", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/tango-card-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Tango Card E-Custom", 
                    "sku" : "TNGO-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "1", 
                    "max_price" : "500000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Amazon.co.jp", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/amazon-jp-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Amazon.co.jp Gift Certificate JPY 500", 
                    "sku" : "AMJP-E-50000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "JPY", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "JP"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "50000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Amazon.co.jp Gift Certificate JPY 1000", 
                    "sku" : "AMJP-E-100000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "JPY", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "JP"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "100000"
              },
              {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard GBP", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-mc-gbp-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard Reward GBP", 
                    "sku" : "PVMGBP-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "75000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard GBP OneClick $3 Diff", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-mastercard-gbp-oneclick-3diff-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard Reward GBP OneClick $3 Diff", 
                    "sku" : "PVMGBPOC-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "75000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard HKD OneClick $3 Diff", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-mastercard-hkd-oneclick-3diff-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard Reward HKD OneClick $3 Diff", 
                    "sku" : "PVMHKDOC-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "HKD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "HK"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "6000", 
                    "max_price" : "1000000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard JPY OneClick $3 Diff", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-mastercard-jpy-oneclick-3diff-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard Reward JPY OneClick $3 Diff", 
                    "sku" : "PVMJPYOC-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "JPY", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "JP"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "600", 
                    "max_price" : "100000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard ZAR OneClick $3 Diff", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-mastercard-zar-oneclick-3diff-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual MasterCard Reward ZAR OneClick $3 Diff", 
                    "sku" : "PVMZAROC-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "ZAR", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "ZA"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "6000", 
                    "max_price" : "1000000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Prepaid Virtual Visa CAD", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/prepaid-virtual-visa-cad-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Prepaid Virtual Visa Reward CAD", 
                    "sku" : "PVVCAD-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "CAD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "CA"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "75000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
                    "description" : "The Great British Pub E-Gift Code GBP 25", 
                    "sku" : "TGBP-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "The Great British Pub E-Gift Code GBP 50", 
                    "sku" : "TGBP-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "The Great British Pub E-Gift Code GBP 100", 
                    "sku" : "TGBP-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "The Home Depot*", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/home-depot-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "The Home Depot eGift Card", 
                    "sku" : "HMDP1-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "200000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "The Restaurant Card", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/restaurantcard-uk-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "The Restaurant Card UK GBP 5", 
                    "sku" : "TRCUK-E-500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "The Restaurant Card UK GBP 10", 
                    "sku" : "TRCUK-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "The Restaurant Card UK GBP 15", 
                    "sku" : "TRCUK-E-1500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1500"
                }, 
                {
            "description" : "The Sports Authority*", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/sports-authority-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Sports Authority eGift Card $5", 
                    "sku" : "SPRT-E-500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Sports Authority eGift Card $10", 
                    "sku" : "SPRT-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Sports Authority eGift Card $25", 
                    "sku" : "SPRT-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Sports Authority eGift Card $50", 
                    "sku" : "SPRT-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Sports Authority eGift Card $100", 
                    "sku" : "SPRT-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Ticketmaster UK", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/ticketmaster-uk-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 5", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 10", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 20", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-2000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 25", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 50", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Ticketmaster UK eGift Card GBP 100", 
                    "sku" : "TKUK-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "TJX*", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/tjx-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "TJX eGift Card Custom", 
                    "sku" : "TJX1-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "50000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "TK Maxx", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/tk-maxx-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "TK Maxx Gift Certificate GBP 10", 
                    "sku" : "TKMX-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "TK Maxx Gift Certificate GBP 25", 
                    "sku" : "TKMX-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "TK Maxx Gift Certificate GBP 50", 
                    "sku" : "TKMX-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "TK Maxx Gift Certificate GBP 100", 
                    "sku" : "TKMX-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "GBP", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "GB"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Tony Roma's", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/tony-romas-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Tony Roma's eGift Card", 
                    "sku" : "TNYR-E-V-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : true, 
                    "min_price" : "500", 
                    "max_price" : "200000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Toys R US*", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/toysrus-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Toys\"R\"Us eGift Card $5", 
                    "sku" : "TOYS1-E-500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Toys\"R\"Us eGift Card $10", 
                    "sku" : "TOYS1-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Toys\"R\"Us eGift Card $25", 
                    "sku" : "TOYS1-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Toys\"R\"Us eGift Card $50", 
                    "sku" : "TOYS1-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Toys\"R\"Us eGift Card $100", 
                    "sku" : "TOYS1-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "description" : "Whole Foods Market*", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/whole-foods-market-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Whole Foods Market eGift $10", 
                    "sku" : "WFOODS-E-1000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Whole Foods Market eGift $25", 
                    "sku" : "WFOODS-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Whole Foods Market eGift $50", 
                    "sku" : "WFOODS-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Whole Foods Market eGift $100", 
                    "sku" : "WFOODS-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "description" : "Xbox Live", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/xbox-gift-card-1.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Xbox Digital Gift Card $15", 
                    "sku" : "XBOX1-E-1500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Xbox Digital Gift Card $25", 
                    "sku" : "XBOX1-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Xbox Digital Gift Card $50", 
                    "sku" : "XBOX1-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "description" : "Zappos", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/zappos-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Zappos E-Gift Card $15", 
                    "sku" : "ZAPO-E-1500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "1500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Zappos E-Gift Card $25", 
                    "sku" : "ZAPO-E-2500-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "2500"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Zappos E-Gift Card $50", 
                    "sku" : "ZAPO-E-5000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "5000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Zappos E-Gift Card $100", 
                    "sku" : "ZAPO-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "USD", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "US"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "description" : "Zattini", 
            "image_url" : "https://dwwvg90koz96l.cloudfront.net/graphics/item-images/zattini-brl-gift-card.png", 
            "rewards" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Zattini Virtual Gift Card BRL 30", 
                    "sku" : "ZTNI-E-3000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "BRL", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "BR"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "3000"
                }, 
                {
                    "description" : "Zattini Virtual Gift Card BRL 100", 
                    "sku" : "ZTNI-E-10000-STD", 
                    "currency_code" : "BRL", 
                    "available" : true, 
                    "type" : "reward", 
                    "countries" : [
                        "BR"
                    ], 
                    "is_variable" : false, 
                    "denomination" : "10000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ] 

}
```

In this json data I will fetch only which are has min_price: 1. here some record doesn't have min_price it has denomination so I need to have only min_price query for mongodb.

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the whole document which has `min_price : 1`

```
db.collection.find({"brands.rewards.min_price" : 1})
```

If you want only the reward whose price is 1

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$unwind" : "$brands"},{"$unwind" : "$rewards"},{$match : {brands.rewards.min_price : 1}}])
```

If it doest not fulfill your requirement please post the output what you want

Comment: i want to pic the all records which is has  min_price is 1

Comment: Yes the second query will give you that please post your output

Comment: while executing getting this error " unwind is not a operator "

Comment: Ohk you can tick the answer if it solved your question

Comment: db.tangoRewards.aggregate( [
   
   { $unwind: "$brands" },{ $unwind: "$brands.rewards" },{ $match:{ "brands.rewards.min_price": {"$lte": "1.0"},
     "brands.rewards.max_price": {"$gte":"100000" }}},
     { $project: { brands: 1 } }

Comment: can u help me parshuram how to write this query in criteria level in java daoimpl

Comment: how to write in java level i mean criteria.where ().is(); like cloud u help

Comment: hi ..parshuram find the solution that nested array json data to fetching what u want actually